# Spring-Boot Custom AuthenticationFilter not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have custom AuthenticationFilter which implements AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter interface. I've set AntPathRequestMatcher but AntPathRequestMatcher not working when i tried connect to login its return 403

My Filter class

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

public JWTAuthenticationFilter() {
    super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "POST"));
}

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication (HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse
    httpServletResponse) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

        String header = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");


        if (header == null || !header.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Token missing or invalid");
        }

        String authenticationToken = header.substring(7);

        JWTAuthToken token = new JWTAuthToken(authenticationToken);
        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(token);
    }

@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
}
```

Configure method

```
http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/sign-up").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    http.addFilterBefore(authTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    http.headers().cacheControl();
```

How can i fix this